# mysqli prepare SELECT not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I must be missing something really obvious or am maybe doing things in completely the wrong way, but I've been looking at this for ages and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm just trying to retrieve a record from a table.  It's not hard; it's just not working!

my code is

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name=? AND user_pass=?");
$sql->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$result = $sql->execute();

echo "<!-- rows = $result->num_rows -->\n";
```

just accept that $db IS a valid connection and there are also error checking statements in the actual code.  The problem is that it's not finding a row and it's not returning an error, in fact $result->num_rows isn't even zero; it's just empty.

The following code works perfectly...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name='$username' AND user_pass='$password'";
$res = $db->query($sql);

echo "<!-- rows = $res->num_rows -->\n";
```

So what am I doing wrong?
`

Answer (score 2):

The [mysqli_stmt execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) method returns a boolean. To get the number of rows use `$sql->num_rows` instead of `$res->num_rows`.

Comment: Thanks for that, now I'm getting a value for num rows, it's just that it's zero when the record certainly does exist.  Am I simply doing things in the wrong way?

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be so much confusion and wrong information out there about using SELECT with prepared statements.  Using documentation from us3.php.net caused me to try using a function which simply doesn't exist!

The thing I seem to be missing was a store_result statement so the logic goes more like...

```
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name=? AND user_pass=?");
    $sql->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->store_result();
    echo "<!-- rows = $sql->num_rows -->\n";
```

I hope this helps someone else who is trying to get this simplest of operations working!

I've still not worked out how (or if) I can do something like $row = $something->fetch_object() or if I'm stuck with having to use bind_result for ALL my table columns but at keast this gets me past the problem of my login page.

Comment: What is that function which "doesn't exist"?

Comment: One always has the option of being helpful or being offensive.  I copied an example from said website and found in the apache error log, "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()".  I assume you have down-voted this answer so please explain why.  This answer works.  You have said nothing helpful or informative.  If you don't know, it's perhaps better to keep your comments to yourself and let those with helpful suggestions provide assistance.